# In Dynamics 365, how to a remember the last active tab after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, tabs, refresh, dynamics-365

When viewing a case, and I refresh the page, I want to navigate back to the tab I was on before the refresh.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don’t think that’s even considered in UCI design. Submit an idea :)

Comment: just an alternate idea, do you use business process flow for a case?
If you do, will it be a close by solution to you to open tab based on active stage, open particular tab?

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a clean way to do this, You need to persist that value between sessions.

The easiest way to accomplish this IMO would be to have an attribute either on the record being viewed, or a related record to store the name of the last tab visited. Each time a tab is changed, the tab name would be updated and saved on wherever record you decide to store it. At minimum you would need to store the record id being viewed, the user doing the viewing, and the name of the tab last viewed. That way you are retaining last viewed tab by user and record.

When the form is opened up, in the OnLoad event, it would query that tab name youve been updating and change the focus to that tab.

This would be supported customization, although possibly not great for performance.

Edit: also depending on your enterprise security settings you may be able to persist the value in a cookie:

```
//use this line to set a cookie
document.cookie = "lastTabVisited=crm_tabname; path=/"

//use this line to help find the cookie you set
document.cookie.split(';')
```